# call UL under a rel in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, list

I'm trying to call the unordered lists under my rel through jquery but I seem to be using the wrong syntax

```
<div class="sun">
        title
        <div rel="subtitle1">
            <ul>
                <li>aaaaaaaaa</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div rel="subtitle2">
            <ul>
                <li>bbbbbbbb</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$(this).hover(function() {
    $('.sun div[rel= "'+ $(this).attr('rel') +'"]').css({color: 'red'});
});
```

So what do I append to the jQuery to tell it that I only want to change the color of the UL, not the whole rel.

I tried:

```
$('.sun div[rel= "'+ $(this).attr('rel') +'"] + ul + ').css({color: 'red'});
```

but that didn't work.

Comment: What's `this` in your first bit of js?

Comment: There is no `rel` attribute for `div` elements. It makes no sense. A `rel` describes the type of relationship that a link is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selector you are building is:

```
.sun div[rel= "subtitle1"] + ul +
```

But you want:

```
.sun div[rel="subtitle1"] ul
```

Remove the `+`s and extra space.

Better yet, stop abusing the `rel` attribute and writing invalid HTML. Use a class. It is what classes are designed for.

```
.sun div.subtitle ul
```

Better still, don't fuss around with JavaScript for this.

```
.sun div.subtitle:hover ul {
    color: red;
}
```

Even better, don't change the appearance of non-interactive elements on hover. Hover effects are a message to indicate things can be clicked.

Comment: I need to use rel for this since classes aren't accepting strings with multiple words. So if I use class, nothing happens when I'm hovering over any of the divs that have longer than one word. Rel does that well for me though. Your solution works though, thank you! And yes I'm not actually changing the color on hover, it's just an example I'm testing out.

Comment: "since classes aren't accepting strings with multiple words" — It's machine readable data, not English. Put hyphens between the words. If you absolutely have to make up your own attribute, then use `data-something` instead of repurposing something with a defined meaning.

Comment: I need them to be multiple words, no hyphen. They're being displayed on the website.